# "error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' function"

Tags: c++

When I try to compile the following code I get the error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' function

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void makedeck(int);

int main(){

int pHand[10]={0};
int dHand[10]={0};
int deck[52];
makedeck(deck); //Error is given for this line
random_shuffle(&deck[0],&deck[10]);

return 0;}

void makedeck(deck[]){
int a=0;
for(int x=101;x<114;x++)
    {
        deck[a]=x;
        a++;
            }
for(int x=201;x<214;x++)
    {
        deck[a]=x;
        a++;
            }
for(int x=301;x<314;x++)
    {
        deck[a]=x;
        a++;
            }
for(int x=401;x<414;x++)
    {
        deck[a]=x;
        a++;
            }

}
```

I tried to imply pointers to parameters somehow but I want to know the actual reason of the problem itself. I just checked another code that is pretty much the same with kinds of variables, parameters, functions and calling of them, however while that one works perfectly, mine fails. Why is it?

Comment: WRONG: `void makedeck(int);`  BETTER: `void makedeck(int * deck);`

Comment: @paulsm4 I should change the prototype?

Comment: Q: Should I change the prototype?  A: Yes, exactly.  As an aside, prototypes are one of the things I love about C++.  But allowing prototypes to have anonymous parameters is one of the things I hate about it :(  I'd strongly encourage you to make the prototype look exactly like your definition, including the parameter name "deck".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of `makedeck` is wrong

```
void makedeck(int);            // Declaration
...
void makedeck(deck[]){         // Definition.
```

They should match - and you have to declare the type of the argument in the definition too.

```
void makedeck(int deck[]);     // Declaration
...
void makedeck(int deck[]){     // Definition.
```

Answer (score 4):

Your declaration of function says that makedeck function has an integer parameter:

```
void makedeck(int);
```

But your actual function definition is different(and seems wrong too), which wants an integer array:

```
void makedeck(deck[]){
```

You just need to fix these two as:

```
void makedeck(int *);
```

and

```
void makedeck(int *deck){
```

Answer (score 1):

You call a function with an int array as an arg, this is a pointer to int, so your function should be like this:

```
void makedeck(int deck[]);
```

or (better):

```
void makedeck(int* deck);
```